# Google admin api push notification - Directory user update

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have a question regarding google admin api push service

When registering for user update push notification, is it posting to my url, when any of the security parameters are changed? parameters such as Authorized access?

(The case as follows: A new user of my domain installs a new application. I want to get a push notification for that event)

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, cGoh, but here we can not just do the work for you, so please provide a minimal test case that showcases your problem.

Comment: the case as follows:
A new user of my domain installs a new application. I want to get a push notification for that.

I read the docs, and I cant figure out if i'm getting push notification for that event